# How do I selectively reset an array's dimensions?

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedimage

I have an abstract class `Sprite`, which, in its constructor, creates an array for individual sprites. The constructor takes the path of the spritesheet, the spritesheet type as an enum, and the individual sprites' widths and heights. The constructor takes the path to the spritesheet, loads it into a BufferedImage, and grabs the individual sprites from the image to load them into an array. Here is the class:

```
package exosoft.Zerfall;

public abstract class Sprite extends Main {
    BufferedImage spriteSheet = null;
    BufferedImage[] sprites;
    int spriteWidth = 0;
    int spriteHeight = 0;

    public enum SheetType {
        SINGLE,
        HORIZONTAL,
        VERTICAL,
        RECTANGULAR
    }
    public Sprite(SheetType type, String sheetPath, int spriteWidth, int spriteHeight) {
        try {
            spriteSheet = ImageIO.read(new File(sheetPath));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        switch(type) {
        case HORIZONTAL:
            sprites = new BufferedImage[spriteSheet.getWidth() / spriteWidth];
            for (int i = 0; i < spriteSheet.getWidth() / spriteWidth; i++) {
                sprites[i] = spriteSheet.getSubimage(i * spriteWidth, 0, spriteWidth, spriteHeight);
            }
            break;
        case RECTANGULAR:
            break;
        case VERTICAL:
            sprites = new BufferedImage[spriteSheet.getHeight() / spriteHeight];
            for (int i = 0; i < spriteSheet.getHeight() / spriteHeight; i++) {
                sprites[i] = spriteSheet.getSubimage(0, i * spriteHeight, spriteWidth, spriteHeight);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is allow the `BufferedImage[] sprites` array to add or remove a dimension based on the given SheetType. For example, here is the switch statement as I'd like it to work:

```
switch(type) {
    case HORIZONTAL:
        sprites = new BufferedImage[spriteSheet.getWidth() / spriteWidth];
        //load sprites into one-dimensional array
        break;
    case RECTANGULAR:
        sprites = new BufferedImage[spriteSheet.getWidth() / spriteWidth][spriteSheet.getHeight / spriteHeight];
        //load sprites into two-dimensional array
        break;
    case VERTICAL:
        sprites = new BufferedImage[spriteSheet.getHeight() / spriteHeight];
        //load sprites into one-dimensional array
        break;
    case SINGLE:
        sprites = new BufferedImage();
        //load sprite into zero-dimensional BufferedImage
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

The goal is to end up with an array named `sprites` with the individual sprites contained, with dimensions as needed. Is this at all possible? Thank you.

Comment: No, it's not possible exactly like you have done above. Your `sprites` member variable needs to be either a normal variable or an array. Why not just always use a 2-dimensional array, and use 1 for the dimension you don't care about? It will always work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is this:

```
BufferedImage[][] sprites=null;

case 0-dimension: sprites=new BufferedImage[1][1];
case 1-dimension: sprites=new BufferedImage[n][1]
case 2-dimension: sprites=new BufferedImage[n][m]
```

then

```
case 0-dimension: sprites[0][0]=new BufferedImage(....);
case 1-dimension: for(i) sprites[i][0]=new BufferedImage()
case 2-dimension: for(i) for(j) sprites[i][j]=new BufferedImage()
```

Comment: This does work, but my goal was to get rid of unnecessary dimensions as needed. Are you implying that this is not possible?

Comment: yes its not possible to have the same variable as undimensional and as an array - other possible solutions are to create a class but then you will have to specify again the dimensionality

Comment: Hmm... I feel like it should be possible, but oh well, I'll have to deal with it, I guess. Thanks for your answer!